# How do I create an array slice using the NumPy C API?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, python-c-api

I want to slice through a 1D NumPy from within a C extension. I see all sorts of helper functions in the C API for creating fresh arrays, reshaping, indexing particular values, etc.. But I don't see anything like PyArray_Slice1D(array, start, stop, step). Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use Python API: create a slice object by `PySlice_New()` and then call `PyObject_GetItem()`:

```
PyObject* PySlice_New(PyObject *start, PyObject *stop, PyObject *step)
PyObject* PyObject_GetItem(PyObject *o, PyObject *key)
```

Comment: This works, but doesn't it create a copy of the data in the original array?